# Flutter - Is there a way to make the Calendar move from year to year?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do a Birth Date picker, and I'm using the "showDatePicker" which is perfect, but I noticed that if I want to choose a date in 1998, I have to scroll a lot.

Is there a way to make this easier for the user? Maybe a way to choose the year?

Here's what I have:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1950),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.dark(),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    ).then((date) {
      setState(() {
        if (date != null)
        dateText = '${date.month}/${date.day}/${date.year}';
        });
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think flutters date / time picker has the functionality you want but there is a nice package that does have it. [Heres](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker#-installing-tab-) the link to install the dependencies its really easy to use and it allows you to scroll through years. Once you have it this is how you implement it.

```
RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Pick Date'),
            onPressed: () => DatePicker.showDatePicker(
              context,
              showTitleActions: true,
              minTime: DateTime(1900, 3, 5),
              maxTime: DateTime.now(),
              onChanged: (date) {
                print('change $date');
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Did this answer your question if so please accept answer if not I'd be happy to further assist you

Answer (score 0):

You could wish to make the user choose the year upfront by providing this parameter in `showDatePicker()`:

```
initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
```